# Prove that every Suslin tree has exactly $2^{\omega}$ branches

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

So I have been assigned this problem in a set theory course, and I have no idea how exactly to approach it. I know that a Suslin tree is an $\omega_1$-Suslin tree, and I also know the proofs for saying that such a tree even exists, but I have no clue how to say anything about the branches of the Suslin tree, much less how to show that there are exactly $2^{\omega}$ branches for every such tree. I've been trying to find some more information to go on, but our class doesn't have a textbook, just lecture notes, so I've spent more time trying to find more resources than anything at this point, and I'm still nowhere closer to coming up with a solution to this. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated because I am just plain lost here.

Comment: A Suslin tree has $\aleph_1$ nodes since its height is $\aleph_1$ and its levels are countable. Also, each branch is countable since a Suslin tree has no cofinal branches. So, how many countable subsets of $\aleph_1$ are there? That's an upper bound.

Comment: Also, one thing to note: there's no outright proof that a Suslin tree exists (i.e. no proof in ZFC). It's consistent that none exist. You probably saw a proof that a Suslin tree exists assuming V=L or $\lozenge$ (or possibly that there is a forcing extension in which one exists).

Comment: Yes we have gone over the fact that we need extra assumptions to even prove that a Suslin tree exists. Also thank you for the hint yesterday it really helped to get the ball rolling on my proof. I have been getting a bit of a better understanding of some of these ideas now.

Comment: Yep, no problem. I hadn't realized at the time that the lower bound is the hard part unless the definition includes some often-assumed properties in addition to the standard ones, e.g. that each node has more than one direct successor or each node has descendants at all levels.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The comment by **spaceisdarkgreen** points the way to an argument showing that a Suslin tree has at most $2^\omega$ branches. To show that it must have at least $2^\omega$ branches, show that the complete binary tree of height $\omega$ can be embedded in it.